# Invalid product id: in app purchase in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, itunes

Hello i am facing a real problem with testing the IAP feature can someone tell me how to solve this issue

here is my code

```
-(IBAction)purchase:(id)sender{

SKProduct *skProduct = _products[0];
NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
      skProduct.productIdentifier,
      skProduct.localizedTitle,
      skProduct.price.floatValue);

NSString *tempTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"InAppTitle", @"Message");
NSString *tempMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"InAppText", @"Message");
NSString *tempRestoreBtn = NSLocalizedString(@"Restore", @"Message");
NSString *tempPurchaseBtn = NSLocalizedString(@"Purchase", @"Message");
NSString *tempCancelBtn = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Message");

NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:tempMessage,skProduct.localizedTitle,skProduct.price.floatValue];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:tempTitle message:temp delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:tempCancelBtn otherButtonTitles:tempRestoreBtn,tempPurchaseBtn, nil];
alert.tag = 456;
[alert show];
```

}

my static.h

```
#define AdmobBannerAdsID  @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

#define AdmobFullScreenAdsID @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

#define ProductIdentifiers @"com.7minute.workout.zerone.remove"
```

this my product id in itunes Connect:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w705y.png)

this is my bundle identifier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGQ3S.png)

Debug area

> 2017-01-10 07:24:52.823 7 MinuteWorkout[39958:433489] Loaded list of products...
>   2017-01-10 07:24:52.824 7 MinuteWorkout[39958:433489] Invalid product id: com.7minute.workout.zerone.remove
>   2017-01-10 07:24:57.440 7 MinuteWorkout[39958:433489] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[**NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ecbd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010592821e objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ee37dd -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:] + 93
>       3   7 MinuteWorkout                     0x000000010226e4ff -[setting purchase:] + 79
>       4   UIKit                               0x00000001024c18bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>       5   UIKit                               0x0000000102647c38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       6   UIKit                               0x0000000102647f51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
>       7   UIKit                               0x0000000102646e4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010252f545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
>       9   UIKit                               0x0000000102530c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
>       10  UIKit                               0x00000001024dd9ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000102cca72d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
>       12  UIKit                               0x0000000102cc3463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
>       13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e70761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e5598c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e54e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e54884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>       17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107e7fa6f GSEventRunModal + 161
>       18  UIKit                               0x00000001024bfc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       19  7 MinuteWorkout                     0x0000000102272a3f main + 111
>       20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109b1068d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: Did you check `_products`, does it have at least one element?

Comment: @nynohu yes i checked